# How to add a User Control in a Panel from a button click of another User Control?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a panel1, 2 user controls uc1 and uc2. uc1 is added to the panel. uc1 has a buttonUC1. When I click that button, I want to hide the uc1 and show the uc2 which has another buttonUC2. By clicking buttonUC2, I want to hide the uc2 and show uc1 in the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can add, show or hide the other control to a panel on the parent form, but instead, it's better to raise an event form the user control that contains the button when the button clicked, then subscribe for that event in your form and do what you need, for example hide your control and show the other user control on the panel on your form.

**To learn more:**

- [Handling and Raising Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Example:**

The code for `UserControl1`:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultEvent("ButtonClicked")]
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Click += button1_Click;
    }

    public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;
    protected virtual void OnButtonClicked(EventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = ButtonClicked;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnButtonClicked(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

And then use the event in your form:

```
private void userControl11_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Button of UserControl1 Clicked!");
    //or for example, userControl11.Hide(); userControl21.Show();
}
```

Don't forget to subscribe for `ButtonClicked` event on your form, using property grid event tab, or code or simply by double click on your `userControl11` on your form at design-time.